# rotate backup files/directories with for loop

Tags: bash

I create a bash function which will move all the backups and archive in a folder with date at every FULL backup like below:

```
  if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/FULL ]; then
    mkdir $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY
    mv $BACKUP_DIR/FULL $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY 
    for dir in $BACKUP_DIR/inc*; do
      mv $BACKUP_DIR/inc* $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY 
    done
  tar -cvf $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY.tar $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY
  rm -rf $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY
  gzip $BACKUP_DIR/$YESTERDAY.tar
 fi
```

The issue is that the loop terminates the function after done. How can I continue with tar after the loop is done each inc directory is copied (inc1, inc2, inc3...)?

Comment: Your question was not clear, Can you explain the issue more about what you are facing and what is your requirement.

Comment: I have this for which will copy all the incremental dirs (inc1, inc2, inc3...) into a folder. It's making the copy successfully but after the loop ends right after "done" it will exit the script and it will not continue with tar function.